# How do I link my Ubuntu server to my GitHub repository?

Tags: ubuntu, github, repository

I have a situation where I developed a Django app and had it linked to a GitHub repository. When I went to the stage of deployment on a Ubuntu server, for a number of reasons we copied the app’s files across to the server directly. I then had to change a number of the files on the server.

This has left me with inconsistencies between the most recent files on the server and the now out of date files on the GitHub repository, and my local machine. Can anyone tell me how to link my server files to update my repository so that I can pull the repository files to my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can learn about CI/CD.

CI/CD automatically does what you configure it to do; upon push to x branch, pull the repository, build the project, connect to your server and deploy it there.

You can use services like [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/hello-world/), [TravisCI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/for-beginners/), [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/)... to aid you with your CI journey.

Edit: Links